# tikz dash rectangle in nest nodes

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I want to use dash rectangle in outer node but use solid rectangle in inner nodes.
But my sample code below actually dashed all node for inner or outer nodes.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  inner/.style={draw,fill=blue!5,thick,inner sep=3pt,minimum width=8em},
  outer/.style={draw=gray,dashed,fill=green!1,thick,inner sep=5pt}
  ]
%---------------------------------------------------%
\node[outer] (A) {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm,outer sep = 0pt]
      \node [inner,minimum width=18em] (A1) {Mr. A};
      \node [inner,anchor=south west,minimum width=8em] (A2) at ([yshift=1em]A1.north west) {Mr. A1};
      \node [inner,anchor=south east,minimum width=8em] (A3) at ([yshift=1em]A1.north east) {Mr. A2};
      \node (text) [anchor=north] at ([yshift=4em]A1.north) {Hello Tikz};
    \end{tikzpicture}
}; 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The output looks like below:

[image]

I only use dashed on outer style but actually inner nodes has got such attribute also! I don't want that!

Comment: Nesting tikz pictures is almost always a bad idea as you can see here. All settings are inherited etc. Use the `fit` library instead

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using `fit` and `backgrounds` for avoiding nested `tikzpicture`. The Zarko's answer is easier than mine but i wanted to illustrate this option. It can be useful in other contexts.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{fit,backgrounds} % <- added
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  inner/.style={draw,fill=blue!5,thick,inner sep=3pt,minimum width=8em},
  outer/.style={draw=gray,dashed,fill=green!1,thick,inner sep=5pt}
  ]
%---------------------------------------------------%
  \node [inner,minimum width=18em] (A1) {Mr. A};
  \node [inner,anchor=south west,minimum width=8em] (A2) at ([yshift=1em]A1.north west) {Mr. A1};
  \node [inner,anchor=south east,minimum width=8em] (A3) at ([yshift=1em]A1.north east) {Mr. A2};
  \node (text) [anchor=north] at ([yshift=4em]A1.north) {Hello Tikz};
\begin{pgfonlayer}{background}
\node[outer,fit=(A1) (A2) (A3) (text)] (A) {};
\end{pgfonlayer}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result is the same.

Comment: Cool, but if I want to use multiple group such things, I wish to treat it as a group for positioning, how can I group this version as one? such as it maybe better to use "below=1cm of A" of B group.

Comment: your *group* is in reality a referenced **node** with *label* `(A)`, so you can use "`below=1cm of A`" whenever you load the `positioning` library.

Answer (score 9):

Try:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
inner/.style={draw,
              solid,% <-- added
              fill=blue!5,thick,inner sep=3pt,minimum width=8em},
outer/.style={draw=gray,dashed,fill=green!1,thick,inner sep=5pt}
                        ]
\node[outer] (A) {
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm,outer sep = 0pt]
      \node [inner,minimum width=18em] (A1) {Mr. A};
      \node [inner,anchor=south west,minimum width=8em] (A2) at ([yshift=1em]A1.north west) {Mr. A1};
      \node [inner,anchor=south east,minimum width=8em] (A3) at ([yshift=1em]A1.north east) {Mr. A2};
      \node (text) [anchor=north] at ([yshift=4em]A1.north) {Hello Tikz};
    \end{tikzpicture}
                };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:**
Nesting `tikzpicture` directly in nodes works just by accident. Better approach is suggested in accepted answer. so here is small variation of it. Positions of nodes are determined by use of the `positioning` library, text "Hello Tikz" in outer node is written as its label:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,
                fit,
                positioning}
                
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
node distance = 2ex and 0em,
inner/.style={draw, thick, fill=blue!5,
              inner sep=3pt,minimum width=8em},
outer/.style={draw=gray, thick, 
              densely dashed, fill=green!5,
              inner xsep=1ex, inner ysep=2ex, yshift=1ex,
              fit=#1}
                        ]
\node (A1)  [inner, minimum width=18em] {Mr. A};
\node (A2)  [inner,above right=of A1.north west] {Mr. A1};
\node (A2)  [inner,above  left=of A1.north east] {Mr. A2};
\scoped[on background layer]
\node [outer=(A1) (A2),
       label={[anchor=north]:Hello Tikz}] {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Good suggestion, that means it has been override actually, but maybe some other things need to rewrite also. do we have method to prevent such heritage?

Comment: In nested TikZ pictures the parameters of outside picture always influence on inside picture. Some times you can help yourself with trick as I show you in my answer, but generally the better approach is given in second answer.